# Smooth path between two points with given turn rate and initial and final direction

Tags: geometry, curves, kinematics

[basic smooth path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkt1i.png)

I'm trying to model the fastest route for a particle to go from one point, heading in a given direction to another point, heading in another direction. This route can have a maximum turn rate that is a given value, theta. In the picture, point/direction A is in blue, point/direction B is in green and the smooth route between them is in red.

I have been attempting to model it with circles and allowing for a reasonable amount of distance to get on the appropriate direction before getting to point B but it is all very ad hoc.

Is there a way to do this more rigorously?

Comment: Is the turn rate the rotation around a fixed center, which would more often be called $\dot {\theta}$ or $\omega$ or some measure of change in the curvature of the path, like how fast one can turn the steering wheel of a car?

Comment: Exactly, or how fast an aircraft or ship could turn.

Comment: Most vehicles are not limited by initiating the turn but by the constant rate that can be maintained in the turn.  That also depends on the speed of travel, as a rough approximation is there is an acceleration level that is the limit.  The vehicle can get to that radial acceleration essentially instantly.  Please make clear what you are asking.

Comment: The radial acceleration can be achieved essentially instantly.

Comment: Another similar question is to say you are traveling at a given speed North and want the fastest way to get to traveling at the same speed South.  You can either accelerate/decelerate linearly at any amount up to $a$ or accelerate radially at any amount up to $g$ but not both.  What is the path and speed history that you should choose?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a limited radial acceleration, the fastest way to turn through a given angle is a tiny radius.  The radial acceleration is $\omega ^2 r$ where $\omega$ is the angular velocity and $r$ is the radius of the turn.  Keeping $r$ small lets $\omega$ get large.  The time to make a $180^\circ=\pi$ radian turn is $\frac \pi \omega$ so you want small $r$ and high $\omega$.  At the limit, in this model you can make the turn instantly at $r=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Given some fixed initial and final conditions ($r$ vector, $x,y,\theta,\rho$ scalars):
$$
r_0=(x_0,y_0), \dot r_0=(\dot x_0,\dot y_0)\\
r_f=(x_f,y_f), \dot r_f=(\dot x_f,\dot y_f)
$$

and the orbit constraint:
$$
|\frac{dr}{dt}|=\dot \theta = \omega_0
$$
The problem is fairly complicated. Suppose you are requested to be at the same vector speed, but just to move to the right, or worst, to keep your position but moving into the opposite direction. You will have to introduce one turn (or a complicated eye shaped turn) just to displace the particle into the requested state.

Please confirm.

I think the best solution for the problem could be forcing the solution into a predefined shape including two circles and a straight line, which is the solution for the simplest cases not involving the longest eye-shaped curve for repositioning the particle. Under that case, the problem "could" be easier to solve. But still complicated.

Check, which i am sure you don t want to program:

- [Optimal Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control),
- [Hamilton Jacobi Bellman Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi%E2%80%93Bellman_equation)

Comment: That is correct. It is possible for the path to have multiple turns and straight segments. It might not be directly calculable.

Comment: This can be very complicated, and i don't think you want a full Optimal Control path, with Lagrangian and Karush Kuhn Tucker conditions iterating through Laplace Multipliers for equality constraints. Which must be done given the problem has discrete constraints. Which is your maths background?

Comment: Also, this is a homework or you need a solution?

Comment: I am making a game and was hoping to allow the player to define point B and show the vehicle transiting along the calculated path. It isn't homework. The work I've done so far has used Optimal Control literature but I've just been taking stabs in the dark translating math directly into code without really understanding what is happening

Comment: Hence, i guess the easiest way should be smoothing the problem, for having a better optimality. But again, programming that optimal problem as is will be a nightmare, even if now you do not understand your code.

Comment: OMG i was needing this answer weeks ago!...